# Jackson support for polymorphism without annotations and dedicated bean fields

Tags: json, polymorphism, jackson

Is there a way to perform serialization/deserialization in Jackson of polymorphic classes w/out using annotations or specialized bean fields?  I have to support class hierarchies that I cannot modify and don't wish to use annotations.

I'd like to be able to designate a synthetic name, which would not be in the classes that I am serializing/deserializing, that would be inserted into the JSON representation and used to identify the type.

Comment: Note that Jackson's Mix-Ins feature facilitates using Jackson annotations without altering any existing class definitions.

Comment: Yes but I still have to create a "do-nothing" class to hang the annotations off of.  This does not appeal to me at all.  What I would like to do is to simply make calls to the object mapper which pass the exact same information as would the annotations.

Comment: For the interested, I logged Jackson issue 728 for an enhancement to provide non-annotation-based subtype registration. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-728 Don't hesitate to vote for the issue if you want it implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If mix-ins are not to your liking, there isn't anything pre-defined to pass, but you can relatively easily achieve this by sub-classing `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` and configure mapper with it.

In your implementation you can override all aspects of annotation access: in your case it's probably enough to override `findTypeResolver()` (and if you want per-property overrides, 'findPropertyTypeResolver()').
The method can then use whatever mechanism you want to construct `TypeResolverBuilder` (most likely `StdTypeResolverBuilder`) that contains same information as what would usually come from `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation.

Comment: Good! This extension mechanism is very powerful, but not very well known... I should probably write a blog post on it, since it can be used for lots of things, esp. where there isn't other in-built ways.

Comment: Am I the only one to think `StdTypeResolver` is an absolutely hilarious name?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for polymorphic json unmarshaling problems, you should check out [this post](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html), which gives great examples & workarounds for JSON serialization / deserialization caveats.

And if *mixins* (step 5 at the above mentioned [post](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html)) is not what you're looking for than go for the accepted answer by *StaxMan*.