# Handel JSON of different type in Spring POST request

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson, http-post

I keep getting Bad request 400 when trying to POST this array of JSON objects "sorry bad format":

```
{
"type":"input","uniqueId":434,"label":"name","viewToCall":"input-configuration-menu"},{"type":"button","uniqueId":930,"label":"name","viewToCall":"button-configuration-menu"}]
```

Im not sure how to handel different type of json object in my @Requestbody:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void saveForm( @RequestBody ArrayList<Components> text ){
        do somthing...
    }
```

I found this resourcer but I dont have the experience to get it to work i n web environment:
[Spring @RequestBody containing a list of different types (but same interface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247189/spring-requestbody-containing-a-list-of-different-types-but-same-interface)
http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html
http://aredko.blogspot.se/2012/04/json-for-polymorhic-java-object.html

Comment: The JSON you posted has an unmatched ] at the end

Comment: it´s just missed it when asking the question

Comment: you might have a problem of content type in headers, show your request's headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing `[` at the beginning of the JSON, otherwise it's valid JSON. If the problem is not the missing angle bracket, put the logs in DEBUG or TRACE, and post the stacktrace.

Also the components need to be annotated with something like this, in order for Jackson to know which object need to be instantiated (see also [Jackson polymorphism without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359831/jackson-support-for-polymorphism-without-annotations-and-dedicated-bean-fields)):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value=Input.class, value="input"), 
    @Type(value=Button.class, value="button")})
public interface Component {
    ...
}

@JsonTypeName("type")
public Sub1 implements Component {
}

@JsonTypeName("button")
public Button implements Component {
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that really helped me, only differens is I used "JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY" and a abstract class. =)